# Is Conv3D different from Convolution3D in Keras?

Tags: keras

For C3D architectures and other C3D-related ones, I am finding different implementations for the 3D convolutional layers in Keras. Sometimes, people use **Conv3D** and sometimes **Convolution3D**.
Are they different ? Is one better than the other ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are exactly the same, Convolution3D was renamed to Conv3D in Keras 2.0, so the difference is just which version of keras the code is targeting.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification !